# Creating an expression tree that calls a method

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, lambda, expression-trees

Is it possible to create an expression tree that directly calls a method? For example, consider the following method:

```
public static int MyFunc(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I would like to create an expression tree that calls MyFunc with parameters a=1 and b=2. One way to accomplish this is with reflection:

```
var c1 = Expression.Constant(1);
var c2 = Expression.Constant(2);
var expr = Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("MyFunc"), c1, c2);
```

However, this is disadvantageous because reflection is slow and turns what should be compile-time errors into run-time errors.

I could use the following approach instead:

```
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> lambda = (a, b) => MyFunc(a, b);
var expr = Expression.Invoke(lambda, c1, c2);
```

But this is still not what I want because it wraps the method in a lambda expression instead of calling it directly.

A good solution might be based on a delegate, like this:

```
Func<int, int, int> del = Program.MyFunc;
var expr = Expression.Invoke(del, c1, c2);
```

Unfortunately, that does not compile because `del` is a delegate rather than an expression. Is there any way to build an expression from a delegate? (Note that I know the target of the delegate at compile-time, so I don't need the kind of flexibility described here: [Expression Trees and Invoking a Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215712/c-expression-trees-and-invoking-a-delegate).)

A non-delegate solution would also be fine, as long as it calls the target method as directly as possible.

**Update:** This also works, but it still relies on reflection:

```
Func<int, int, int> del = Program.MyFunc;
var expr = Expression.Call(del.Method, c1, c2);
```

At least it is more likely to catch problems at compile-time. But it still pays the run-time price for reflection, doesn't it?

Comment: More information about the use-case would be useful :) e.g. with the examples you've given you might as well be passing around a plain `Func<int,int,int>`... (and you say you know the target at compile-time) so what is the `Expression` tree required for?

Comment: Compiling an expression is going to dwarf the overhead of reflection. Since you only perform the reflection once when you make the expression, its cost is going to be negligible.

Answer (score 12):

As long as you call `.Compile` on the lambda and store (and re-use) the delegate, you only pay the reflection price once.

```
var c1 = Expression.Constant(1);
var c2 = Expression.Constant(2);
var expr = Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("MyFunc"), c1, c2);
Func<int> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(expr).Compile();
// ** now store func and re-use it **
```

However, to get a *naked* delegate to **just** that method, you can use:

```
var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("MyFunc");
Func<int, int, int> func = (Func<int, int, int>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
         typeof(Func<int, int, int>), method);
```

of course, then you are forced to provide the constants at the caller.

Another option is `DynamicMethod`, but as long as you are caching the final delegate, this won't be *significantly* faster. It does offer more *flexibility* (at the price of complexity), but that doesn't seem to be the issue here.